# Opening android app on certain fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

Upon launching an app - how can you launch it on a certain tab fragment? So rather than just opening on say.. `tab1` it opens on `tab3`

The code for the main activity.

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    Tab tab1;
    Tab tab2, tab3, tab4, tab5;
    Fragment fragmentTab1 = new FragmentTab1();
    Fragment fragmentTab2 = new FragmentTab2();
    Fragment fragmentTab3 = new FragmentTab3();
    Fragment fragmentTab4 = new FragmentTab4();
    Fragment fragmentTab5 = new FragmentTab5();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        android.app.ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

        tab1 = actionBar.newTab().setText("Item 1");
        tab2 = actionBar.newTab().setText("Item 2");
        tab3 = actionBar.newTab().setText("Item 3");
        tab4 = actionBar.newTab().setText("Item 4");
        tab5 = actionBar.newTab().setText("Item 5");

        tab1.setTabListener(new MyTabListener(fragmentTab1));
        tab2.setTabListener(new MyTabListener(fragmentTab2));
        tab3.setTabListener(new MyTabListener(fragmentTab3));
        tab4.setTabListener(new MyTabListener(fragmentTab4));
        tab5.setTabListener(new MyTabListener(fragmentTab5));

        actionBar.addTab(tab1);
        actionBar.addTab(tab2);
        actionBar.addTab(tab3);
        actionBar.addTab(tab4);
        actionBar.addTab(tab5);


    }
}
```

So using this, the app launches on `tab1`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should be able to do:

```
actionBar.addTab(tab1, false);
actionBar.addTab(tab2, false);
actionBar.addTab(tab3, true);
actionBar.addTab(tab4, false);
actionBar.addTab(tab5, false);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do the following inside onCreate:

```
 @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState)
 {
     //do everything you would normally do here
     ....

     viewPager.setCurrentItem(2);
 }
```

That is all you need to open your app with tab3 selected.

Comment: Hey thanks for commenting - I have added `ViewPager viewPager;` to the top and then as you have suggested in the implementation - however when `viewPager.setCurrentItem(2);` is visible (ie not commented out) the app crashes on launch saying `Unfortunately (app name) has stopped"

Comment: I need to see the logcat. Do you have a view pager in your xml file?